# How to backup SSD if MacBook doesn't turn on?

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, ssd, power

I have a MacBook Pro 15" Mid 2015 and after 3 years of using it, I think it is broken since it won't power on. I already tried resetting SMC and NVRAM but it's still not working. I don't hear any chimes or any fan noises and my charger is still working properly. I tried charging it for more than 3 hours but the light is always orange/amber. I guess this is a logic board issue.

I went to an Apple Center to get it fixed but they advised me to backup my SSD first because they don't do this service and they will wipe all of my files so they can diagnose it properly.

**So my question is:**

How do I backup my SSD when my MacBook doesn't even turn on? I'm guessing I need to remove the SSD but I don't know what to do after remove it.

Comment: You can use a SSD case to use it to boot other Macs.

Comment: Hi @Pratik! Thanks for your answer. Can you make it more detailed? After I put it in a SSD case, I'll plug it in on a different mac? I'm using a macbook air atm. Can you make it more detailed? Sorry, if I ask a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I backup my SSD when my MacBook doesn't even turn on? I'm
> guessing I need to remove the SSD but I don't know what to do after
> remove it.

#### You are correct; you just need to remove it.

What you do afterwards is put it in a safe place (like a desk drawer).

Why?

**There's no need to erase, much less even *have*, an internal SSD to diagnose and repair a power issue.**

If the "Apple Center" (you didn't say if they were an actual Apple Store or an authorized 3rd party repair facility) said that "wiping" the drive was necessary, I would look for another facility.

You can boot a MacBook from USB, another SSD, or from another MacBook (via Target Disk Mode) so there's no reason that they should get yours (as a side note, they should have spare ones with clean OSes for diagnostics). An internal drive is absolutely not necessary for diagnosis/repairs (unless of course the issue is the SSD itself). As it's a power issue, the SSD is irrelevant and shouldn't even be touched.

#### The fix...

The problem that you are experiencing is related to the [DC-in board](http://radnex.us/mbp_15-inch_DC-in_board) (aka the MagSafe board).

[image: 2015 MacBook Pro 11,2 DC-IN board]

Besides being the interface for your charger to your MacBook, it acts as a safeguard to ensure that you're not dumping 18V DC into your SMC (which handles power) that only takes 3 volts. (It's also very inexpensive).

It's not a complex fix, but it is detailed as you do have to remove the logic board. [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2015+Logic+Board+Replacement/56210) has an excellent step-by-step walk through on how to do this.  However, if this is not your cup-of-tea, I advise taking it in.

That said...**you should be backing up on a regular basis.**

Comment: I really hope this will fix it since logic boards are quite pricey.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting the Mac in [target disk mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25318?locale=en_AU) by holding the T key on bootup. Connect it to another Mac using a thunderbolt 3 cable (note: if you don't have one, it's probably not worth it to go out any buy one as this most likely won't work). If the broken mac shows up on the other mac, copy the files from it to your second computer.

If that doesn't work, you probably need to take out the SSD and get an adapter to connect it to another computer and copy the files.

[Follow this guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2015+SSD+Replacement/48251) to take out the SSD from your computer. Keep in mind that this does come with risk and some tools will be needed. You can also ask an Apple Store and you can pay a bit to have them take it out.

[I found a (rather expensive) enclosure](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MAU3ENVOYPRO/) that you can put the SSD in when you take it out, however there is a most definitely a cheaper one out there.

### **In the future, back up your drives.**

Comment: The MBP doesn't turn on, so, how to you boot it in Target Disk Mode?

Comment: if you can't boot it into target disk mode, like I said, it won't work

Comment: also, the answer above was probably right as well. i didn't think about it in my original post, but, yeah, there should be no reason why they should have to wipe your drive for a power related issue